# MVC 3 Model Validation Issue - Oversight or By Design

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

**I ran into a scenario where I needed to know which property was currently being validated** in a custom `ValidationAttribute`. I assumed this would be easy in MVC 3 since the `ValidationContext` is being passed into the [`IsValid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd730022%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method.

Without going into detail, here is the basic idea:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {

   if (ShouldICareAboutYou(validationContext.MemberName))
   {
       //Do some stuff
   }

   //Return the results
}
```

This seemed like the perfect solution, and indeed, when unit testing my custom ValidationAttribute using [`Validator.TryValidateObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411772%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) everything worked beautifully!

**HOWEVER...**

When calling [`TryUpdateModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel.aspx), or [`TryValidateModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryvalidatemodel.aspx) within my controller, the validation runs, but `ValidationContext.MemberName` is null.

**Whaa Huh?!?**

I did a little investigation and sure enough, right there inside of [`DataAnnotationsModelValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.dataannotationsmodelvalidator.aspx) is the code... or lack thereof.

```
public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container) {
    // Per the WCF RIA Services team, instance can never be null (if you have
    // no parent, you pass yourself for the "instance" parameter).
    ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(container ?? Metadata.Model, null, null); 
    context.DisplayName = Metadata.GetDisplayName();

    // Setting the MemberName here would be trivial!
    // However, philh told me not to. Something about
    // a guy named Josh who pushed him down on the playground
    // in middle school.

    //context.MemberName = Metadata.PropertyName; (Suck It, Josh!!!)

    ValidationResult result = Attribute.GetValidationResult(Metadata.Model, context); 
    if (result != ValidationResult.Success) {
        yield return new ModelValidationResult { 
            Message = result.ErrorMessage
        };
    }
}
```

I realize that `DisplayName` *could* be the property name if no `DisplayAttribute` has been applied to the property. Unfortunately I can't really deal in hypotheticals. I need to know **exactly** what the property name is.

**So what is the deal? Is this by design or an honest oversight.** If it is an oversight, then it would be awesome to get this fixed in MVC 4 :)

### Disclaimer:

The *added* comments in the code sample above are meant to be funny. I do not know, nor have I ever met [Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/articles/AboutHaacked.aspx). From what I can tell he seems like a really nice guy. And pushing him down in middle school would have made me a royal douche!

Comment: +1 for lighthearted comments. The world needs more smiles. :)

Comment: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/729

Comment: Just a followup on @Michael's link above. There's a fix for this in MVC 5.2, released in July.

Comment: @jdmcnair - Sweet! And I'm pretty sure I only know one jdmcnair :)

Comment: Yeah, that would be me. Now you can go finish that code you had to set aside 3 years ago ;)

Comment: @jdmcnair - Believe it or not I actually managed to work around it, although it would have been much, much simpler had this not been broken.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem and decided to pass in the property name as a parameter in the attribute constructor and then store it in the attribute. For example:

```
[MyValidationAttribute("MyProperty")]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Then in MyValidationAttribute.cs:

```
public class MyValidationAttribute
{
    private string PropertyName;

    public MyValidationAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        this.PropertyName = propertyName;
    }
}
```

It is a little annoying that now I have to type the name of my property twice but it solves the problem.

Comment: Believe it or not, this is pretty much exactly what I ended up doing as well.

Comment: It's maybe an old post, but i came up with the following solution to avoid manually providing the property name.

```c#
public CustomAttribute([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
```

Answer (score 3):

Josh,

Frustrating, yes.

However, for your purposes, you can create your own class inheriting from `DataAnnotationsModelValidator`, override the `Validate()` method, and uncomment that line of code that is taunting you.  Then, in Global.asax.cs, clear `ModelValidatorProviders.Providers` and add your class.

Not an optimal solution, but one that will get you to where you need to go.

Comment: True, and I may end up going down that road. However, I don't want to do something that drastic without first knowing that it won't screw up something in some subtle way. Probably not, but I am still holding out hope that someone on the MVC team might decide to enlighten the rest of us as to the design decision.

Comment: You are more likely to hear from the team by posting this as an issue at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic.

Comment: Could you explain how to implement that? Should I write own DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider?

Comment: @EvgeniNabokov - Now that the whole thing is open source, you could just pull the code down and fix it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter` or `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapterFactory` method for your attribute type and providing your custom `ModelValidator`.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and this question set me on the right tracks. I fixed it by changing my custom validator to populate MemberName when ValidationResult is created, like so (note the second parameter in ValidationResult constructor):

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(Object value, ValidationContext     validationContext) {

   if (ShouldICareAboutYou(validationContext.MemberName))
   {
       //Do some stuff
   }

   return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), new string[] { validationContext.MemberName });
}
```