# Custom Validation : get the property name from validationContext

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-validation

For my ASP.NET MVC projects, I created a custom validation attribute. Here is the code I am struggling with :

```
  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {

        //Here I need to resolve the url in order to make a call to that controller action and get the JSON result back

        var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(
            new System.Web.Routing.RequestContext(
                httpContext, new System.Web.Routing.RouteData()
            )
        );
        var url = urlHelper.Action(Action, Controller, null, 
            urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme);

        var fullUrl = string.Format("{0}?{1}={2}", url, 
            /*validationContext.MemberName*/"term", value);

        if (!GetResult(fullUrl)) {

            var message = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
            return new ValidationResult(message);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

You can see the full code from below link :

https://bitbucket.org/tugberk/tugberkug.mvc/src/6cc3d3d64721/TugberkUg.MVC/Validation/ServerSideRemoteAttribute.cs

For the `fullUrl` variable, I am trying to append the property name to querystring but when I use `validationContext.MemberName`, I am failing. I solved the problem with a temp fix by making it static as "term" but it is not a fix at all.

So, what is the way of retrieving property name from `validationContext`?

Comment: I have the same problem. I even want to go further and get all the CustomAttributes for the property being validated. Sadly the validationContext doesn't contain any useable properties/methods to get this information.

Comment: This is answered here with more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447932/mvc-3-model-validation-issue-oversight-or-by-design

Answer (score 3):

Does validationContext.DisplayName do the trick?

You could then reflect to get the MemberName

```
var displayName = validationContext.DisplayName;

var memberName = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<DisplayAttribute>().Any(a => a.Name == displayName))
    .Select(p => p.Name)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Possibly?

Comment: DisplayName and the MemberName is different.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right - in my code I had to choose between being able to access the name of the member (via DisplayName) and having a DisplayAttribute on that member.  I'm going to edit my answer with apossible solution though

Comment: Sorry, been hectic today - I should be more careful with responding :)

Comment: No problem at all :) hmm, I will definately give it a try. you could send a patch if you want as well: https://bitbucket.org/tugberk/tugberkug.mvc/src/6cc3d3d64721/TugberkUg.MVC/Validation/ServerSideRemoteAttribute.cs

Comment: More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447932/mvc-3-model-validation-issue-oversight-or-by-design

Comment: and if you have two properties with same displayName?